# How to check zoom level is below 100% (ctrl and - ) in each browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, zooming

In the browser by default the user can either use ctrl +/-  or ctrl scroll to zoom in or zoom out the page. I would like to know is there any way to check the zoom level is below 100% and not doing something

eg. My code

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).height() > 500 && $(window).width() > 600 && $('.royalSlider:visible').length < 1 && !isiPhone()){

        //Not allow the page size < 0
        Book.zoom_auto();
        Book.book_position();
        Book.dragdrop_init();   

        if ($(".viewportBinder").length){                   
                $("#view").css('height',$(window).height());
                $("#view").css('width',$(window).width());  
                content = element.viewport('update');     
        }
    }
calculate_zoom_factor();
});
```

currently window resize is implement some function but I would like to add condition **only zoom level >= 100%**  , thanks

Comment: This might help u: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078596/1624583

Comment: http://htmldoodads.appspot.com/dimensions.html

Comment: I found this website and it solved my problem

Comment: @user782104 Then post it as an answer to help other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the window size using [this reference](http://htmldoodads.appspot.com/dimensions.html)

From the website, you can find that the zoom level is below 100% if

```
$(window).width() >= screen.width
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Firefox 28.0.

Comment: This also doesn't work if browser isn't full screen.

Comment: If developer tools is opened to the right (in Chrome) then `screen.width` will also include that.