# Detect browser zoom level

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with border-right property. When my site is zoomed out the div size will adapt but the border will still stay the same size. This results in the div moving outside its parent. 
Is there a way to detect the zoom level? So that I could change size depending on the zoom.
And if so, then how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870651/how-to-check-zoom-level-is-below-100-ctrl-and-in-each-browser this might help you as well

Comment: There is a way to detect the zoom level, but it's harder than it sounds, and gets really complicated when trying to move elements based on zoom etc.

Comment: The browser tries to optimize as best as it can.  I wouldn't bother with this unless you have a specific reason for doing so.

Comment: Sounds to me like this issue should be adressed in CSS itself.

Comment: How is the border-right defined, and what browser are you using? A quick test shows that the border width does shrink when zooming out on all browsers I tried.

Comment: @Mr Lister   I'm using border-right: 1px solid; And I've tried in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: 1px you say? Yes, it is difficult to shrink below that. So, what do you get, rounding errors.

Comment: See: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/detect-browser-zoom-level/

Answer (score 3):

```
var zoom = window.outerWidth / window.document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

Comment: Doesn't work with FF; reports the same value for `window.outerWidth` and `window.document.documentElement.clientWidth`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `border-width` is `1px`, you can't shrink below that, so what I would suggest is:

- in the resize event, check if the browser has changed zoom using a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)
- set the `border-width` to `0px` if the zoom level is under `100%`